# Приложение pyqt под android

Tags: android, python, pyqt5

Подскажите пожалуйста как десктоп программу на pyqt переделать под андроид или такое вообще возможно

Comment: Нашел немного информации - может вам поможет: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436340/pyqt-on-android

Answer (score 1):

пишешь свой код на pyqt -> используешь утилиту pyqtdeploy для заморозки (компиляция в с++ qt проект с ***.pro файлом) -> идешь в qt creator и компилишь код под андроид/иось/шиндовс/линух/макось
у меня на старте были проблемы только с хедерами и версиями python (подходит только третяя)